# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token @import css

Tags: css, extjs

**EDIT**: It was a typo - I used script instead of link by mistake and didn't notice. Because there is already a correct answer given, I won't delete the question even if it's stupid. I'll just accept the answer instead.

I'm trying to learn **ExtJS**.
I've written the simple code below. I added the neptune theme css file in order to style my components, but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

The error ocurrs at the imports inside the aforementioned file:

```
@import 'theme-neptune-all_1.css';
@import 'theme-neptune-all_2.css';
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "ext-6.6.0-trial/build/classic/theme-neptune/resources/theme-neptune-all.css"></script>
      <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "ext-6.6.0-trial/build/ext-all.js"></script>

      <script type = "text/javascript">
         Ext.onReady(function() {
            Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
               renderTo: 'helloWorldPanel',
               height: 200,
               width: '50%',
               title: 'Hello world',
               html: 'First Ext JS Hello World Program'
            });

         });

      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "helloWorldPanel" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is telling the browser it's about to read javascript, then giving it CSS.  You want to load your CSS with a `link` element, not a `script` tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: Now I see... It was a typo - I used script instead of link by mistake and didn't notice. Anyway I'll accept this answer because it's correct, and I will not delete this stupid question. Thank you!